# Magento 2 : How add validation validator to custom input field in checkout page?

Tags: checkout, payment-methods, magento2.2.3, validation, input

We have to add custom form in check-money order payment method.We have to add custom validations before order placement but its not working.
please check below code

1)**Create the validator**:-

> Custom_Checkmethod/view/frontend/web/js/model/custom-validation.js

```
define(
    [
    'jquery',
    'mage/validation'
    ],
    function ($) {
        'use strict';
        return {
            validate: function() {
                $.validator.addMethod(
                        'checkmonumber',
                        function (value) {
                            return true;
                        },
                        $.mage.__('Please enter number')
                    );
               return true;
            }
        }
    }
);
```

2)**Add validator to the validators pool:-**

```
define(
    [
        'uiComponent',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/additional-validators',
        'Custom_Checkmethod/js/model/custom-validation'
    ],
    function (Component, additionalValidators, yourValidator) {
        'use strict';
        additionalValidators.registerValidator(yourValidator);
        return Component.extend({});
    }
);
```

**Checkout Form** :-

```
<fieldset data-bind="attr: {class: 'fieldset payment items allbank ' + getCode(), id: 'payment_form_' + getCode()}">
    <label data-bind="attr: {for: getCode() + '_checknumber'}" class="label">
        <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Check Number'--><!-- /ko --></span>
    </label>
    <div class="control">
        <input data-validate="{'required-entry':true, 'validate-number':true}" type="text" name="payment[checknumber]" class="input-text required-entry checkmonumber" value=""
               data-bind="attr: {
                                id: getCode() + '_checknumber',
                                title: $t('Check Number'),
                                'data-container': getCode() + '-checknumber',
                                'data-validate': JSON.stringify({'required':true})},
                                valueUpdate: 'keyup' "/>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

4)**Declare the validation in the checkout layout**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
<referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="additional-payment-validators" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <!-- Declare your validation. START -->
                                                        <item name="your-validator" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Custom_Checkmethod/js/view/add-validator</item>
                                                        </item>
                                                        <!-- Declare your validation. END -->
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

when we click on place order button then add input field validation.I am not able to how to add it?please tell me how to validate input field.

Comment: have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

inside in your custom-validation.js

I don't see any validation there

so try to add

```
 $.validator.addMethod(
                        'checkmonumber',
                        function (value) {
                           if (value == null) { return false; }
                          // numerical validation or write your custom logic
                          return /^[0-9]+$/i.test(value);                             

                        },
                        $.mage.__('Please enter number')
                    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the JavaScript Validation Logic

```
define([
'jquery',
'mage/translate'
```

], function($, $t) {
'use strict';

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    'custom-validation',
    function (value, element) {
        // Your validation logic here
        // Return true if the field is valid, false otherwise
    },
    $t('Your error message here.')
);
```

});